# How do I use gdrive to upload a file to a Google Drive directory?

Tags: command-line, google-drive, upload

I have a Google Drive directory called `Ward`.

I'm using `gdrive`, which is an otherwise wonderful tool, but I can't get it to upload to a directory.   For example this works (my utility is called `gdrive` not the usual `drive`):

```
gdrive upload filename.pdf
```

This will send the file to the Google Drive home directory.

But trying the instructions from `gdrive help upload`,

```
gdrive upload -p Ward filename.pdf
```

throws an error `file Ward not found`.

Comment: gdrive is not working anymore is there any option now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because the `-p` flag is looking for a Parent ID and "Ward" isn't a valid ID. Unfortunately life is not as simple as just using the plain English folder name!

You can find the ID of a folder by navigating to it in Google Drive, then look at the URL. It will be something like:

`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dJqBRKIgUMKPipCtsAifIHpEmOUfRd7j?ths=true`

The ID is this bit:

`1dJqBRKIgUMKPipCtsAifIHpEmOUfRd7j`

Try finding that for the Google Drive folder you're wanting to upload to, then use that in the `-p` flag instead of "Ward" and it should work.